# Add blur with CSS radial gradient

Tags: css, css-filters, css-gradients

I am trying to create a "focus" effect with CSS. I have managed to add some background color and use radial-gradient to create *almost* what I want. See the [pen](https://codepen.io/taut-and-yare/pen/rNyrRpm) below (in the pen I used an img instead of a video for simplicity):

```
<div class="focus" />
<video src="https://some-video" />
```

```
.focus {
    top:0;
    left:0;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:100;
    height:100vh;
    width:100vw;
    background: radial-gradient(
        circle at 50% 50%,
        transparent 150px,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) 160px
    );
}
```

Is there a way to add a blur filter instead of opacity?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34458137/2135738), but as mentioned in the comment on that answer, I would like a solution that would allow for dynamic content without replicating html tags (wouldn't like to have to deal with 2 video elements...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use backdrop filter combined with mask:

```css
.focus {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  -webkit-mask: radial-gradient(circle, #0000 150px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) 160px);
  backdrop-filter:blur(10px);
}

body  {
  background:url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1598128558393-70ff21433be0?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=844&q=80) center/cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="focus">

</div>
```

Comment: This seems to ignore background-fliter, just opacity is applied in your pen I believe...

Comment: @user2135738 you are probably testing with FF, you need to use Chrome. Firefox doesn't support backdrop-filter

Comment: I am on chrome. The filter works, but when I add this rule `mask: radial-gradient(circle, #0000 150px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95) 160px);` then bluring stops and opacity applies

Comment: @user2135738 is the code working fine in the above snippet?

Comment: No, check this out in the pen: If you comment-out the mask rule, the writing on the pencil is not legible, but with the mask on it is just opaque https://codepen.io/taut-and-yare/pen/MWpqmQR

Comment: @user2135738 use an opaque color, replace 0.9 by 1 in the color of the mask

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`backdrop-filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter) and [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path). If you want to blur the inner circle you can achieve something like this:

```css
.blur {
    top:0;
    left:0;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:100;
    height:100vh;
    width:100vw;
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    clip-path: circle(40%);
}
```

```html
<div class="blur">
</div>

<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1598128558393-70ff21433be0?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=844&q=80" />
```

---

> The backdrop-filter CSS property lets you **apply graphical effects such as blurring** or color shifting to the area behind an element. Because it applies to everything behind the element, to see the effect you must make the element or its background at least partially transparent.
>
> Source: [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter)

> The clip-path CSS property creates a **clipping region that sets what part of an element should be shown**.
>
> Source: [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)

---

#### if you would like to apply gradient too:

```css
.gradient, .blur {
    top:0;
    left:0;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:100;
    height:100vh;
    width:100vw;
}

.blur {
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    clip-path: circle(40%);
}
.gradient {
    background: radial-gradient(
        circle at 50% 50%,
        transparent 150px,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) 160px
    );
}
```

```html
<div class="blur">
</div>
<div class="gradient">
</div>

<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1598128558393-70ff21433be0?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=844&q=80" />
```

---

Just be careful with browser support.

- `backdrop-filter` [is not supported by IE11, FF for Android etc.](https://caniuse.com/css-backdrop-filter)
- [neither `clip-path` is](https://caniuse.com/?search=clip-path)

Comment: at least don't add the last one which is aleardy in my answer. that's the purpose of having *multiple* answers

Comment: @TemaniAfif didn't read your answer cause it came later than mine but ok, we can keep it in your. Just provide some information about that "_mask_".

Comment: I need the inverse, as in the answer of @TemaniAfif, but that answer seems not to filter just opacity finally