# How to add a backdrop blur filter as a gradient

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am trying to achieve a backdrop blur effect that using a gradient. I have been able to apply the blur but not make it have a gradient. I am using Tailwind so any help with using those classes would be great.

This is the result I am looking for (or something close to it), where line isn't harsh.

[image]

Here is an example using plain CSS.

```css
.content {
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  height: 420px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.overlay {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">

  <img width="800" src="https://149351115.v2.pressablecdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/121220-Stackoverflow-Motivation-Alex-Francis-2048x1075.jpg" />

  <div class="overlay">
    <p>hello world</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67906184/8620333 ? mask combined with the filter and the gradient goes inside the mask

Comment: Are you able to provide an example? I have tried with `-webkit-mask: -webkit-gradient(...)}` however I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this by adding a mask to the div.

```
  -webkit-mask: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left 45%,
    left 0%,
    from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)),
    to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0))
  );
```

Thanks to [Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif) for the suggestion.