# CSS Blur with Gradient

Tags: css, sass

I am looking at creating a bar that sits behind my navigation that blurs, but fades the transparent at the bottom.

I currently have achieved the blur effect fine, however it has a natural line where it ends - which I want to fade to transparent so no matter what appears on the website, it fades to nothing - if that makes sense?

[Current blurred navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WH9o2.png)

Below is the code used, that sits inside the navigation bar:

```
<div class="c-blur"></div><!-- /.c-blur -->
```

Then I have the following SCSS:

```
.c-blur {
    &:before {
        content: "";
        backdrop-filter: blur(12px);
        -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(12px);
        -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, black $height-header, transparent);
        position: absolute;
        inset: -1px 0 0;
        pointer-events: none;
        user-select: none;
        opacity: 0;
        .has-sticky-nav &,
        .has-sticky-nav-scrolled & {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your code with minor changes works just fine for me with FF and Chrome.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you CSS Blur based on a gradient mask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648881/can-you-css-blur-based-on-a-gradient-mask)

Comment: @Jared - what minor changes are needed to achieve what I am looking for - as it doesn't fade to transparent at the bottom.

Comment: @CBroe - I have looked at the examples on that link and it doesn't seem to do what I am looking for.

Comment: If https://codepen.io/antoniandre/pen/vYpWQXd?editors=0100 is not what you want, then we'll probably going to need a better explanation of what exactly you have in mind then.

Comment: Ok, I will try again. I have a sticky navigation on my website that has a blur effect behind it, that when I scroll through the website, the navigation bar is blurry overlapping the content. The problem is once the height of the bar ends, the blur ends abruptly. What I want is the blur effect to start at the top of the sticky bar and end at the bottom - so like a gradient type effect, but the bottom line fades to nothing (transparent). Does that help?

Comment: @craigjoe changes - just moved to pure CSS. Here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/JaredSpb/pen/rNZLwzG

Answer (score -1):

modify your SCSS code as follows, blurred navigation bar will have a gradient that fades to transparent at the bottom,opacity will smoothly transition when  navigation bar sticky

```
.c-blur {
  position: relative;
  
  &:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    inset: -1px 0 0;
    backdrop-filter: blur(12px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(12px);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
    pointer-events: none;
    user-select: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out;
    
    .has-sticky-nav &,
    .has-sticky-nav-scrolled & {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
}
```